# How can i find out the maximum amount of ram supported for my computer?

Tags: laptop, memory, ramdisk, hardware-detection

I want to upgrade ram for my old laptop but i am a bit confused.. what is the difference between pc3 and ddr3 or how many mhz should it be, so what can be the highest.. can you help me? Screenshot from CpuZ https://i.stack.imgur.com/sf66w.jpg

[CPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpPXB.png)

[MainBoard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYyC3.png)

[Memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyQ0U.png)

[SPD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udj2H.png)

Comment: Go to crucial.com

Comment: @Gantendo Error because my computer is old